# My Company name changed by Apple?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

We have got two individual accounts. Names are Mavi Digital Media and Mavi Mobile. Apple  removed company names and wrote their own personal names from Appstore. Why?
Mavi Mobile was replaced with ZZ MM.
Mavi Digital Media was replaced with XX YY.
We want to use Mavi Mobile and Mavi Digital Media.  any solution? thanks

Comment: A little more context would do wonders. What service are you even referring to?

Comment: Apple changed your company name where ?

Comment: This is a question for Apple Developer Relations (check out the link provided in Matt's answer), not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either:

1. Email Apple.
2. Phone Apple.

You can find the contact information here - https://developer.apple.com/contact/

There's no reason I can think of that Apple would just change it out of the blue. So, contact them and ask them.